# How to modify this script to make Page2 loads out of the iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Here is my code, and I'm looking for a solution to make that, on timeout, Page2 open out of the iFrame. Any help or idea really appreciated. Thx.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>MyFile</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var frames = Array('http://www.mydomain.com/files/Page1', 55,
    'http://www.mydomain.com/files/Page2');
    var i = 0, len = frames.length;
    function ChangeSrc()
    {
    document.getElementById('frame').src = frames[i++];
    if (i >= len) return; // no more changing
    setTimeout('ChangeSrc()', (frames[i++]*1000));
    }
    window.onload = ChangeSrc;
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <iframe src="" name="frame" id="frame" width="100%"height="100%></iframe>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "open out of the frame"?

Comment: Please re-writing the question, it is not clear what you're trying to achieve. And seeing your code, it creates even more confusion. By the way, have you tried something different than the code exposed here?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wacky with your code :)

- having the URLs and timeout values intertwined in a simple array "smells". I'd recommend an array that contains simple objects.
- don't use the `Array` function to create simple Arrays. Use literals instead.
- don't use eval-style strings as parameters for `setTimeout`

To answer your actual question, let me simply show you this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/SE2jH/